# one to many relationship in Laravel5 is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a collection controller

looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Middleware\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\User;
use App\Invoice;
use Session;
use Validator;


class CollectionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

  public function __construct(){

    $this->middleware('role:collector'); // replace 'collector' with whatever role you need.
}
   public function getPayment($invoiceid){


         $id =$invoiceid;
         $invoice=Invoice::where('Id', $id)->with(['payments'])->get();


         return View('collectionmodule/payment')->with(array('invoice'=>$invoice));

 }
```

}

Then I have following models 
**Invoice**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    //
     protected $table = 'event_invoice';

     public function payments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\paymentrecieved','invoice_id');
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\comments','invoice_id');
    }
}
```

**Paymentrecieved**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class paymentrecieved extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'paymentrecieved';

    public function invoice(){

            return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');

        }


}
```

So for every Invoice there could be multiple payments .

So in My getPayment method I am writing Query like this .

```
$invoice=Invoice::where('Id', $id)->with(['payments'])->get();
```

Its getting me the Details from Invoice table . But its not getting me any Payment Details

Any one know why is this happening , According to me I have done the relationship properly

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Id` (with uppercase) for the primary key, but the Invoice model is looking for the `id` (with lowercase).

You should define the primary key in the `Invoice` model like this:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
```

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::load()` I am getting this error

Comment: I have to get All the payments of the invoice which has Id as $id

Comment: I tried your Last edit but its giving me following error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::payments()`

Comment: And this isn't work? `Invoice::with('payments')->where('Id', $id)->get();`

Comment: sure I was thinking the same , Which website I can use to show the dump ?

Comment: Paste it in your question.

Comment: You get back the payments, but it is empty. I think your relation is wrong. You have invoices and every invoice has one payment method, right?

Comment: But One Invoice can have multiple payments actually , So How my relationship is wrong

Comment: sorry I think I am explaining wrong , See The invoice is geerated only once , But the payment is being collected multiple times, So In my Payment collection form I have to show how many payments had been done for that invoice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94579/discussion-between-vikram-and-kotapeter).